# Using new Python on old CentOS, but only for certain services?

Tags: python, linux, centos, trac, centos5

I am using `Trac` issue tracking system version 0.12 on CentOS 5.8.

I am also using `Agilo for Trac` plugin. This plugin needs Python 2.5 and CentOS 5 comes with Python 2.4.

Is it possible to install additional Python version 2.5 parallel with current 2.4 and to somehow force Agilo for Trac to use the new Python while everything else on server would keep on using old Python? How to do it?

Comment: That sounds like a job for virtualenv (as mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv, virtualenv -p /opt/blah/python2.5 <path/to/new/virtualenv/> will create a virtualenv that you can run stuff inside using the alt python.  With that said, I've heard issues with running stuff in modwsgi with different versions of python but don't know if that applies to Trac or not.

Comment: you can download the source and install it to different prefix. so that you can keep multiple python versions. then either you can create softlinks or use the python path to use the python(2.4/2.5) which you want.